# Unknown Method key? error in Rails 2.3.8 Unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was writing unit tests for my models for a while. After that I was tweaking around and again continued writing unit tests.

Earlier all my unit tests were working - successfully. But now WHen I run them, it gives me

```
Loaded suite unit/post_test
Started
EEEE
Finished in 0.112698 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_presence_of_body(PostTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x103519a88>


  2) Error:
test_presence_of_body_and_title(PostTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x1034dd420>


  3) Error:
test_presence_of_title(PostTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x1034af750>


  4) Error:
test_title_minimum_width_3(PostTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x103481a80>
```

And my test cases are

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase


  def test_presence_of_title
    post = Post.new(:body=>"Some content")
    assert !post.save,"Saved post without title"
  end


  def test_presence_of_body
    post = Post.new(:title=>"Some title")
    assert !post.save,"saved post without body"
  end


  def test_presence_of_body_and_title
    post = Post.new(:title=>"Some title",:body=>"")
    assert !post.save,"Saved Post without body"

    post = Post.new(:title => "",:body=>"Some body")
    assert !post.save,"Saved Post without title"

    post = Post.new(:title =>"",:body=>"")
    assert !post.save,"Saved Post with title and body"


  end


  def test_title_minimum_width_3
    post1 = Post.new(:title=>"a",:body=>"This will not be saved")
    assert !post1.save,"Saved post with title length less than 3"

    post2 = Post.new(:title=>"abcd",:body=>"This will be saved")
    assert post2.save,"Couldnot save a valid post record"

    post3 = Post.new(:title=>"abc",:body=>"This will be saved")
    assert post3.save,"Could not save a valid record"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was working and now it is not, I would say that you might have introduced some kind of error in your post model.  It is difficult to say without a backtrace and code from your post model, but if you were to run the same code in your console, do you get the same error?

```
post = Post.new(:body=>"Some content")
post.save
```

From there you should get a backtrace and a place to hunt the error down.

EDIT:

Next I would try running rake with the `--trace` flag to get a backtrace.

The other thought I had was that it might be something monkey patching assert.  I don't see anything about test unit changing assert method to take a hash as the second argument.

first, go into your console and type, `assert false, "error message"` and you should get a no method error.  If you get another response, then you need to find where the assert method might be, otherwise - try with this:

```
require 'test/unit'
include Test::Unit::Assertions
assert false, "error message"
```

You should see:

```
Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError: this is a message.
<false> is not true.
```

Otherwise, I would also try removing the message at the end of your assert and see if you get the same error.

Comment: no- When I do the same thing in console, it just acts normally. No error /backtrace.

Comment: I get the same error even if I do the above steps. I also tried to add a dummy test within a test block as " assert true"  .. still that error fails with the same error message "NoMethodError: undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x103519a88>"